# What is the difference between class(val a: Int) and class(a: Int)?

Tags: scala, class

What is the difference between `class(val a: Int)` and `class(a: Int)`?

From the decompiled code I can see that in the `class(val a: Int)` version, there is an accessor for `a`.
But what is the difference from a higher level?(I mean from the semantic level)

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference might be best illustrated with a couple of trivial sample classes:

```
class X(a: Int)

class Y(val a: Int)

val x = new X(1)
x.a
// <console>:28: error: value a is not a member of X
//        x.a

val y = new Y(2)
y.a
// res1: Int = 2
```

`a` in class `X` serves nothing more than a mere constructor parameter and cannot be treated as a class member, whereas `val a` in class `Y` serves as both a constructor parameter and a class member.

Answer (score 3):

The high-level difference is that `a: Int` means that `a` is only visible **inside** the class, whereas `val a: Int` means that `a` is also visible **outside** the class and in subclasses.

**Note:** This only affects external visibility; you can still use `a` in class methods even if it is not `val`, because the scope of `a` is the whole class definition.

For example, this is valid Scala:

```
class A(a: Int) {
  def apply(b: Int) = a*b
}
```

Also note that `a` cannot be re-assigned in either case, even if it is not marked `val`.

In practice the value of `a` is always in the class, but Scala will only generate a `get` method if it is declared `val`.

Answer (score 1):

`class(a: Int)` defines a as an argument to the default constructor of `class`

`class(val a: Int)` defines a public field `a` that is set by an argument to the default constructor of `class`